# Rotate a point around another causes the distance between the two to shorten after eeach iteration

Tags: android, graphics

As the title specifies, after each iteration the distance between the two points shortens.

(I need the x, y to be ints ant the end)

Thank you !

```
public void updatePlayerFlip()
{
    double angle_stepsize = 0.1;
    double angleInRadians = angle_stepsize * (Math.PI / 180);
    double cosTheta = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
    double sinTheta = Math.sin(angleInRadians);

flipPosition.x = (int) (cosTheta * (flipPosition.x - spinPosition.x) -
                        sinTheta * (flipPosition.y - spinPosition.y) + spinPosition.x);
flipPosition.y = (int) (sinTheta * (flipPosition.x - spinPosition.x) +
                        cosTheta * (flipPosition.y - spinPosition.y) + spinPosition.y);
}
```

Comment: and your problem actually is... ?

Comment: it's not a circular motion, it is a swirl one, the end-product after a full rotation is not a circle

Comment: its because you ignore the fractional part:  flipPosition.y = (int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your positions as floating-point values and only convert to int when you need to use the result as an int. For example, assuming `DoublePoint` is a double-precision floating point class that represents the x and y position, and `IntPoint` is an integer point class, you could do something like this:

```
class Player {
    DoublePoint position;

    IntPoint getIntPosition() 
    { 
        return IntPoint((int)position.x, (int)position.y); 
    }

    void RotatePosition(double radians)
    {
        DoublePoint newPos;
        newPos.x = position.x * cos(radians);
        newPos.y = position.y * sin(radians);
        position = newPos;
    }
};
```

Then do all your calculations in floating point (like in the `RotatePosition()` method). When you need the integer value, call `getIntPosition()` rather than directly using `position`.